# How to make ng-multiselect-dropdown always open never close,is there any way

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using [ng-multiselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown) ,I am using it in a dialog box ,just want that option always open but in their document nothing is there.

Comment: The question is not properly formatted. Please follow the [StackOverflow Questions Guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that others could help you.